# Bluetooth not disable programmatically in android API 31 or higher version

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-settings

I'm trying to disable Bluetooth on the button click but it not work

hear, What I Do

```
if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
    if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) && checkPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)) {
        BluetoothAdapter adapter = ((BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE)).getAdapter();
        if (adapter != null) {
            if (adapter.getState() == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {
                Log.e("BT", "disable");
                adapter.disable();
            } else if (adapter.getState() == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF) {
                if (!adapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                }
                Log.e("BT", "enable");
            } else {
                Log.e("BT", "Else");
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(UltimateHomeLauncherActivity.this, "Bluetooth is not supported on your hardware", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        List<String> deniedPermissions = new ArrayList<>();
        deniedPermissions.add(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
        deniedPermissions.add(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
        requestRuntimePermissions(1011, deniedPermissions.toArray(new String[0]));
    }
}
```

I'm add Bluetooth permission in Manifest also.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

`android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT` is a [runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#declare-android12-or-higher) and requires the consent of the user.

However, with next API level 33 [enable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#enable())/[disable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#disable()) of the BluetoothAdapter will be deprecated and are not longer allowed. Therefore, it is probably best for such a function to navigate the user to the Bluetooth system dialog and ask him to turn the function on or off there.

Comment: I'm taking user permission also and Everythings is working fine but the issue only that I cannot turn off Bluetooth programmatically

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to turn on/off Bluetooth in Android

1. `BluetoothAdapter.enable()` to turn on Bluetooth

   `BluetoothAdapter.disable()` to turn off Bluetooth

   These methods are asynchronous and  will only work below API level 33
2. Or use

`{ Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE); startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT); }`

to turn on Bluetooth

`{ Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISABLE); startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISABLE_BT); }`

to turn off Bluetooth

Upon execution, a system dialog will prompt the user to turn on/off Bluetooth.

Once turned on/off onActivityResult() override method will be triggered.

In your case, you are using `BluetoothAdapter.disable()` try using the other method.

Comment: There is no public constant `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISABLE`, but using the `"android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISABLE"` value explicitly works.