Bluetooth Adapter Enable or Disable Not Working
I was writing some code to turn on or off bluetooth adapter. But the problem is that I am using android 14 and it is not working. It calls the method but bluetooth still dooes't turns off if enabled or on if not enabled. I don't know why this issue occurs. Can you please provide me some solution. I think this method is deprecated for latest SDK. But still can you please tell me solution
Here is my code

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION = 100;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private TextView tvBt;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private final BroadcastReceiver bluetoothReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action != null && action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
                updateBluetoothStatus(state);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializing Button and TextView
        Button btnBt = findViewById(R.id.BtBtn);
        tvBt = findViewById(R.id.BtTv);

        // Check for Bluetooth permission
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION);
            }
        }

        // Initialize Bluetooth adapter
        BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        if (bluetoothManager != null) {
            bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "BluetoothManager is null");
            tvBt.setText("Bluetooth is not supported on this device");
            return;
        }

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter is null");
            tvBt.setText("Bluetooth is not supported on this device");
            return;
        }

        // Register for Bluetooth state change broadcasts
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, filter);

        // Set initial state of Bluetooth in TextView
        updateBluetoothStatus(bluetoothAdapter.getState());

        // Set OnClickListener for the button
        btnBt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to disable Bluetooth");
                    boolean success = bluetoothAdapter.disable();
                    if (!success) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to initiate Bluetooth disable");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to enable Bluetooth");
                    boolean success = bluetoothAdapter.enable();
                    if (!success) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to initiate Bluetooth enable");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission not granted");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION);
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateBluetoothStatus(int state) {
        switch (state) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                tvBt.setText("Bluetooth is ON");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                tvBt.setText("Bluetooth is OFF");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                tvBt.setText("Bluetooth is turning ON");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                tvBt.setText("Bluetooth is turning OFF");
                break;
            default:
                tvBt.setText("Bluetooth state unknown");
                break;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth status updated: " + tvBt.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted, proceed with Bluetooth operations
                updateBluetoothStatus(bluetoothAdapter.getState());
            } else {
                // Permission denied, disable Bluetooth operations
                tvBt.setText("Bluetooth permission denied");
                Log.e(TAG, "Bluetooth permission denied");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Unregister the receiver when the activity is destroyed
        unregisterReceiver(bluetoothReceiver);
    }
}

I tried to turn off bluetooth when it was on , but it didn't work. I am using android 14. I have all neccessroy permissions
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bluetoothcontrol">

    <!--Put the permissions between the manifest and application opening tags-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Bluetooth">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>



https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73882349/bluetooth-not-disable-programmatically-in-android-api-31-or-higher-version/76339684#76339684

Both the BluetoothAdapter.enable() and BluetoothAdapter.disable() functions you use work as intended. They are there for backwards compatibility, but do nothing in the context of a user application.
The reason for this is simple: Bluetooth is used by a lot of applications these days, and if one of them could disable Bluetooth, all the others wouldn't work either.
